# Are there any strategy to solve this system of multivariate quadratic equation?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, multivariable-calculus

Solve:
$$
(\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_{j})(\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}y_{j})=0, \quad i=1,\cdots, 2n-1\\
\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}y_{j}=0
$$
,where $a_{ij}$ are known real constants and $x_{j}$ and $y_{j}$ are nonzero unknowns to be solved in $\mathbb{Q}$.

The motivation of this question is trying to decompose a set of vectors $a_{i}$ into two hyperplanes with orthogonal normal vectors.

P.S. Thanks to S.B.'s comment. In my specific application, $a_{ij}$ are generated so that a nonzero solution is guaranteed to exist and the number of $a_{i}$ always exceeds the dimension of the space in question. I know that they belong to two such subspaces, but I want to know which.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I think you might have mistyped the indices for that first sum. Is it $\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}x_{j}$ or $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_{j}$?

Comment: I want to express that the first equation is a set of equations for $i=1,\cdots,n-1$. Should I add this behind the first equation? OK, I've add it. Sorry for that.

Comment: Why is it guaranteed to have a solution at all?

Comment: It does not have a solution, except zero, for most general cases indeed. But in my specific application, $a_{ij}$ are generated so that at least one nonzero solution is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: @user25654 I think $a_i$s need to be linearly **dependent** otherwise you only have $x=y=0$ as a solution.

Comment: @S.B. Yes, but not only that.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent phrasing of these statement (in terms of matrix multiplication) which may be helpful is
$$
x^T (A^TA)y=0\\
x^T y=0
$$
Where $A$ is the matrix of entries $a_{ij}$ and $x,y$ are column vectors of the $x_j$ and $y_j$ entries.

It seems useful that $A^TA$ is symmetric, which means it has an orthonormal eigenvector decomposition. Perhaps this will lead to further insight.

Comment: Thank you for your post, but I think your first equation is the sum  of all equations involving $a_{ij}$, which is not equivalent to the original system.